# Apache mod_proxy balancer config issue with POST request

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I am trying to setup a Load balancer with Apache mod_proxy and Tomcat. 
I have the following modules available (mod_proxy, mod_proxy_balancer, mod_proxy_http)
I have 2 Tomcat instances and the plan is to route the request to one of the Tomcat server.

My application on Tomcat is running fine when I directly access.
www.mydomain:8080/myapp
www.mydomain:9080/myapp

My Tomcat server.xml has the following
Tomcat 1
Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat1"

Tomcat 2
Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat2"

Here is what I have in my virtualhost.conf

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
        ProxyRequests on
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
        ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp /

        <Proxy balancer://mycluster >
                BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/myapp route=tomcat1
                BalancerMember http://localhost:9080/myapp route=tomcat2

                Require all granted
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>

    <Location /balancer>
        SetHandler balancer
        Require host www.mydomain.com
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

With the above configuration I am able to access the site first page. When I access www.mydomain.com, it loads the login page(www.mydomain.com/login.do)
When I click on other links it's opening the correct pages. For eg: www.mydomain.com/password-reset.do
The basic fail over also works. If I shutdown one Tomcat Instances, it serves the page from the other server and vice versa.

But when I try to submit any POST requst like try to Login, the url change to www.mydomain/myapp/login.do and always shows the login page.

I am not sure the above conf entries are fully correct with respect to what I want.
Can some one points me what is wrong. Also please let me know if I am lacking anything here with respect to sucurity.
I also would like to have image files and other files served directly from the Webserver. Please let me know how I can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases when this usually happens. It doesn't involve balancer - it happens all the same with a single backend.

1. A place in the HTML of application could contain a literal absolute URL like http://example.com/myapp/post_here so POST goes there (which in fact hits backend with http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/myapp/myapp/post_here). There is a broad range of solutions to this.
2. Another possibility. The POST usually results in a redirect (302). The backend might redirect to an absolute URL http://example.com/myapp/post_here which wouldn't be catched. Your ProxyPassReverse presently only catches http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/myapp/post_here. You can add `ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/myapp` below yours as an additional one, it's allowed.

Both cases are simple to observe if you set your browser to log network requests/responses (developer option in both Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: All URLs used are relative URL. No absolute URLs used.

If I view source my login page I have the following.
<form .... action="/myapp/login.do" method="post">

I tried what you mentioned, but didn't fix the issue.

When I open the Dev Tools on Chrome and view traffic, I see the following
Request URL: http://www.example.com/myapp/login.do
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

At the same time if I access my Tomcat directly, there is no issue. All works perfect. So I assume the issue somewhere with my proxy setting.